# Get every ID from HTML-Code which contains certain Css-Value

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, getattribute

Im trying to get every ID from HTML-Code which contains certain Css-Value and write them into a List.

I already can get the first ID by using:

```
List<string> MyList = new List<string>();
int Count = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("My_Value")).Count;

for(int i=0; i<Count; i++)
{
     string ID = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.My_Value")).GetAttribute("id");

     MyList.Add(ID);
}
```

The problem is, that i always get the first ID from the HTML-Code althoug MyValue exist in different ID´s. So how can i tell the programm to 'Jump' the allready checked Values?.

Comment: Do you have link to the webpage that you trying to get the kids from, that will help troubleshoot. If you do, update your question with those details please

Comment: Unhappily can not link to the website, because the website is a company internal one.

Comment: Any chance you can provide a grab of the dom expanded that you are looking at, add it to your question, so a static consideration of your issue can be looked into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

You have to use a var variable to safe all the element´s. And get the ID´s through a foreach Loop.

```
List<string> MyList = new List<string>();

var ID = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.My_Value"));

foreach(IWebElement element in ID)
{
     element.GetAttribute("id")
     MyList.Add(ID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine, but it is not running a loop, as you say it is finding the 1st element that matches your criteria, then is complete. To get all of them, try:

```
string ID = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.My_Value")).GetAttribute("id");
```

Not tried this myself , but give it a go

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn´t work. `FindElements` doesn´t contain a methode like `GetAttribute()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are constructing the list using `By.TagName("My_Value")` only the `<My_Value>` elements will be collected and put into the list, i.e.

```
<My_Value>class="foo bar"...</My_Value>
```

Moving forward, within the loop `FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.My_Value"))` identifies only the `<div>` elements with *class* attribute as `My_Value` i.e.

```
<div>class="My_Value"...</div>
```

So the outer `FindElements()` and innerloop `FindElement()` doesn't match. Hence you don't get all the values.

---

### Solution

To iterate over all the collected list elements you need to use:

```
string ID = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("My_Value")).GetAttribute("id");
```